# How to move name of axis in Plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I have example like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

data1<-data.table(rbind(c(0,'Very long text'),c(4,'Very, very, very, very long 
text')))
colnames(data1)<- c('A','B')

plot_ly(data=data1,y=~A, x=~B,type='bar') %>%
layout(xaxis=list(tickangle=45),
     margin=list(b=200))
```

And problem is that the name of xaxis is close to xaxis and it can interfere with tick labels.

Is there possibility to move downward name of xaxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (now) an option called `standoff` which can be set in the title layout which controls the distance between the axis and the title.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

data1<-data.table(rbind(c(0,'Very long text'),c(4,'Very, very, very, very long 
text')))
colnames(data1)<- c('A','B')

plot_ly(data=data1,y=~A, x=~B,type='bar') %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(tickangle=45, title = list( text ="my title", standoff = 50)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have started using annotations to make my own axis labels where I want them and how I want them. Check out the annotations "example" under layout at https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/. There is a small learning curve but then you are in charge.

**Sample**

```
var layoutS = 
{  
   title:'Plot',
   xaxis1:{  
      zeroline:false,
      zerolinewidth:1,
      showline:true,
      showticklabels:true,
      ticks:'outside',

   },
   yaxis1:{  
      zeroline:true,
      zerolinewidth:1,
      showline:true,
      showticklabels:true,
      ticks:'outside',

   },
   width:graphWidth,
   height:graphHeight,
   annotations:[  
      {  
         xref:'paper',
         yref:'paper',
         x:0,
         xanchor:'center',
         y:1.1,
         yanchor:'bottom ',
         text:'x[n]',
         showarrow:false
      },
      {  
         xref:'paper',
         yref:'paper',
         x:1.1,
         xanchor:'left',
         y:0,
         yanchor:'top',
         text:'n',
         showarrow:false
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Congrats on your first SO answer and welcome to the community! Please note that link-only answers are strongly discouraged since URLs tend to disappear over time. If you could reproduce the gist of the linked page in your answer, that would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: As per the suggestion, here is a piece of javascript that shows what I mean:

Comment: **Sample**:
var layoutS =
{
title :'Plot',

xaxis1:
{
zeroline: false,
zerolinewidth: 1,
showline: true,
showticklabels: true,
ticks: 'outside',
},

yaxis1:
{
zeroline: true,
zerolinewidth: 1,
showline: true,
showticklabels: true,
ticks: 'outside',
},
width: graphWidth,
height: graphHeight,

annotations:
[
{
xref: 'paper', yref: 'paper',
x: 0,
xanchor: 'center',
y: 1.1,
yanchor: 'bottom ',
text: 'x[n]',
showarrow: false
},
{
xref: 'paper',
yref: 'paper',
x: 1.1,
xanchor: 'left',
y: 0,
yanchor: 'top',
text: 'n',
showarrow: false
}
]
};

Answer (score 0):

Plotly [documentation](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis) does not list an option for moving `xaxis` title. Easiest (but nasty) workaround is using `\r\n` in `xaxis=list(tickangle=45, title = "\r\n B")`.

Comment: Maybe one `\r\n` is not enought to spot the difference. Try following xaxis=list(tickangle=45, title = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n B")

Comment: Ok, idea is good, but it works with <br> instead of \r\n.
So, it will be like that: `xaxis=list(tickangle=45, title = "<br><br><br> B")`.
Thanks for help.